# Incluir HTML em HTML sem afetar SEO

Tags: html, seo

Já vi várias formas de incluir um arquivo *HTML* dentro de outro *HTML*, tanto por *JavaScript* como pela tag **`<object>`** do *HTML5*.

Estes tipos de include afetam negativamente o SEO da página?

O conteúdo incluído dessas formas são indexados normalmente pelos mecanismos de pesquisa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muito provavelmente o Google Bot não leva isso em consideração e entende a página toda como um único documento.

Ele solicitará a página e obterá o código HTML, PHP, ASP, etc que for gerado de volta, por isso não se importa se é uma página estática ou uma página gerada (como a maioria dos sitem em Wordpress ou Joomla por exemplo que basicamente são um monte de `includes`. Ele nunca verá o código do servidor, apenas o resultado renderizado que a requisição retornou para o browser.

Acessando uma página não é possível dizer com certeza se é uma página stática ou "dinâmica" (gerada dinamicamente) e entregue para o browser. Muitas páginas geradas têm uma extensão de arquivo diferente que páginas estáticas (por exemplo, .aspx ou .php em vez de .html), mas as páginas geradas também podem ser imprimidas com a mesma extensão de arquivo de página estática.

Como disse anteriormente, eu particularmente não acredito que o Google Bot não vá indexar as otimizações SEO de arquivos indexados de forma dinâmica em outra páginas. Vc pode até fazer um teste AP para comprovar isso, mas se ele não interpretasse isso 90% dos site Wordpress não teriam seu conteúdo rankeado.

Artigo sobre o assunto que pode te interessar. Nele foram feitos diversos testes e o resultado foi o que se segue: https://centrical.com/test/google-json-ld-and-javascript-crawling-and-indexing-test.html

*O seguinte pode ser concluído.*

- *O Google rastreia e indexa todo o conteúdo que foi injetado pelo javascript.*
- *O Google até mostra resultados na SERP baseados em conteúdo injetado de forma assíncrona.*
- *O Google pode manipular conteúdo de httpRequest ().*
- *No entanto, JSON-LD, como tal, não leva necessariamente a resultados de SERP (em oposição às entidades SERP oficialmente suportadas que não são apenas indexadas, mas também usadas para decorar a SERP).*
- *O JSON-LD injetado é reconhecido pela ferramenta de teste de dados estruturados, incluindo a injeção do Gerenciador de tags. Isso significa que, uma vez que o Google decida apoiar as entidades, a indexação não será um problema.*
- *Elementos meta atualizados dinamicamente são rastreados e indexados também.*

*Então, muito em breve, os dias de pré-renderização de instantâneos do PhantomJs e de fornecimento de conteúdo de sombra para as aranhas acabarão. Isso me faz feliz.*

**OBS 1:** Tenha em mente que o conteúdo que é renderizado no front-end do lado do cliente pode não ser indexado pelo Google, então se vc plotar alguma coisa na tela do cliente apenas no user-side sem nenhum tipo de requisição no servidor pode ser que o Google não indexe esse conteúdo.

**OBS 2:** o Google tem uma ferramente que pode te ajudar a rastrear os dados estruturados que vc está indexando na sua página e se eles estão sendo identificados, vc pode consultar aqui https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

**Dica:** Tenha atenção com as URLs. Nesse artigo tem algumas dicas sobre como tratar o SEO em páginas dinâmicas. https://thecontentworks.uk/dynamic-pages-seo-friendly/

---

**Sobre os `iframes`**

> Google supports `frames` and `iframes` to the extent that it can. Frames
>   can cause problems for search engines because they don't correspond to
>   the conceptual model of the web. In this model, one page displays only
>   one URL. Pages that use frames or iframes display several URLs (one
>   for each frame) within a single page. Google tries to associate framed
>   content with the page containing the frames, but we don't guarantee
>   that we will.

**Traduzindo:** *O Google suporta `frames` e `iframes` na medida do possível. Os frames podem causar problemas para os mecanismos de pesquisa porque eles não correspondem ao modelo conceitual da Web. Nesse modelo, uma página exibe apenas um URL. As páginas que usam frames ou iframes exibem vários URLs (um para cada frame) em uma única página. O Google tenta associar o conteúdo indexado à página que contém os frames, mas não garantimos que o faremos.*

***Fonte:*** https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34445?hl=en

Artigo com testes de SEO feitos utilizando iframes https://www.searchlaboratory.com/2017/09/iframes-and-seo/