# Motores de busca ignoram includes no php?

Tags: php, html5

Se tratando de montar uma página web usando outras páginas o iframe é uma das opções mais simples, mas estudando sobre o assunto eu descobri que eles não são recomendados porque os motores de buscas ou leitores de tela ignoram seu conteúdo quando passam pelo frame.

Outra forma de montar uma página usando outras seria usando o include do php, mas aí surge a mesma dúvida: quando um motor de busca ou leitor de tela passa pelo include, ele lê o conteúdo da página/arquivo ou também ignora?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Incluir HTML em HTML sem afetar SEO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/315553/incluir-html-em-html-sem-afetar-seo)

Answer (score 0):

O código PHP é processado no servidor. O documento que o browser (cliente) recebe é o resultado desse processamento, portanto os motores de busca não saberão da existência do include.